# Razor and linq expression

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, lambda, razor

I've the following.

```
<td>@((IEnumerable<IAccountProductItem>)Model.Data).Sum(i => i.Live)</td>
```

At the moment its output System.Linq.Enumerable+d__3a`1 ......... to the page and I want it to be evaluated and output as the sum i.e 44

Any ideas? Sure this is simple.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an MVC person, but it sounds like you're mostly missing brackets. Try:

```
<td>@(((IEnumerable<IAccountProductItem>)Model.Data).Sum(i => i.Live))</td>
```

Hopefully this will convince the Razor engine that the whole expression is what you want evaluated, not just the bit before `.Sum`.